# WPF owner window on top of child window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

Is it possible for Owner window in WPF be on top of Child window when you click on it while Owner window is below Child window?

here is example how I call child window:

```
Window2 window = new Window2();
window.Owner = this;
window.Show();
```

Parent/Owner window will always be under child window.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, I'm still having trouble understanding how you want your windows to behave. Thanks!

Comment: Lets say we have Window1 and Window2. Window1 is set as Owner of Window2 (code in question in running in context of Window1, "this" is Window1). When Window2 is on top of Window1 (in z axis, so dragged over), Window1 will always be under Window2. So my question is: Is it possible for Window1 to be over/on top of Window2 and how?

Comment: The only solution I could get to work is to not make Window1 owner of Window2, and yet, it has it's problems. Window2 would appear BELOW window1.

Comment: I have needed a similar thing. I needed my main window to keep track of all child windows that are open, and once user clicks on any of the windows I want that window to be the most top one. Is that something you need to achieve? As far as I know owner is always behind the windows it owns and there is nothing you can do to change that. The only way is to keep the track of child windows yourself.

Answer (score 7):

To get the behavior you want, you don't want to set the Owner on either window.

You, of course will have to handle the logic yourself when closing either of the windows to close your imaginary "child" window.

There may be some other logic you'll have to implement related to minimizing, maximizing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation.  I solved this by simply removing the owner after showing the window.

```cs
Window2 window = new Window2();
window.Owner = this;
window.Show();
window.Owner = null;
```

Edit:
Someone replied to this, and while looking at it, I decided I wanted to make an extension method.

```cs
public static void ShowAsIfChildOf(this Window childWindow, Window parentWindow)
{
  childWindow.Owner = parentWindow;
  childWindow.Show();
  childWindow.Owner = null;
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the answers on this page involve *nulling*-out the `Window.Owner` property for some or all of the (*non-*`MainWindow`) windows in your `System.Windows.Application`. While this is a simple and easy fix that does indeed, in isolation, fix the issue of `Window` overlap, unfortunately it also inhibits a lot of useful application-wide functionality that **WPF** seems otherwise eager to provide in the areas of:

- `Application` acti­vation/deactivation (via mouse-click, desktop <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switching, etc...),
- correct observance of the [`Application.​ShutdownMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode) property, and generally,
- orderly cleanup, resource disposal, and exit of your `Application` upon shutdown.

It is possible fix the `Window` overlap issue while still preserving these system-wide WPF features by instead designating a ***special invisible window*** instance as your `Application.MainWindow`.

Modify your application so that the first `Window` it creates--which is the `Window` that gets assigned to `Application.MainWindow`--is a special dummy `Window` that is then made invisible by setting its `Visibility` to `Visibility.Hidden` or calling `Window.Hide()`. This will not hide its owned windows. Then, ensure that your desired "main" window containing your true content, plus all the other windows, owned by this invisible window.

Once hidden, the dummy `Window` will not show in the Windows 10 taskbar. You can set the `Window.ShowInTaskbar` property on whichever of the visible windows you deem appropriate  to simulate apparent special designation, as required.

This approach allows any of the visible windows in your `Application` to be on top of the others, while still preserving WPF features and behaviors for system-wide app activation. For example, when the `Application` is activated (by clicking on any one of the windows, or via Alt-tab), all of the application's windows are together brought above any other desktop app windows, ***while still preserving the most recent "in-app" Z-order***. WPF shutdown functionality is also preserved, including correct observation of the `Application.ShutdownMode` logic in accordance with the invisible `MainWindow` (or all the others) being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the solution mentioned by Licht

```
Window2 window = new Window2();
window.Owner = this;
window.Show();
window.Owner = null;
```

seems to me to be the same as

```
Window2 window = new Window2();
window.Show();
```

i.e., as if no ownership relationship has been set, i.e., when you close the owner window the owned windows do not close, etc., and may not be a solution when one would wish to have all of the ownership relationship features except "An owner window can never cover an owned window."

> Once this relationship is established, the following behaviours are exhibited:
>
> - If an owner window is minimized, all its owned windows are minimized as well.
> - If an owned window is minimized, its owner is not minimized.
> - If an owner window is maximized, both the owner window and its owned windows are restored.
> - An owner window can never cover an owned window.
> - Owned windows that were not opened using ShowDialog are not modal. The user can still interact with the owner window.
> - If you close an owner window, its owned windows are also closed.

The best solution here looks to me to be the one with **hidden main dummy window** described by Glenn Slayden, at the link below, though it would be nice if there was a simpler one.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110288/19683309

Answer (score 0):

Don't set Owner for child window, then in MainWindow handle OnClosing event like this:

```
private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object? sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window is Window appWindow)
        {
            if(appWindow.Equals(Application.Current.MainWindow))
                continue;

            appWindow.Close();
        }
    }
}
```